# Three.js spherical coordinates formula

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, spherical-coordinate

I'm trying to figure out what is going on in next example
https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html (the sphere version)

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
    var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;
    var object = new THREE.Object3D();

    spherical.set( 800, phi, theta );
    object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );
    ...
}
```

I read some math articles (there were just explanations of converting spherical coordinates to Cartesian) and found this question
[Can someone explain the formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584643/can-someone-explain-the-formula).  It was impossible for me to leave a comment there due to my reputation, however after all of that I still don't understand how did they get these two formulas.

```
var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;
```

So my questions are:

1) How do you get these formulas?

2) Why was the length of objects used to get phi and theta?

Answer (score 4):

Note that `phi` varies from Pi to 0 corresponding to arccosine law, while `theta` linearly depends on `phi`. So combination of these angles form spiral on hemisphere surface (given code does not contain clues to make the second hemisphere).

Arccosine law provides equidistant coils (loops? don't know exact term for spiral turn). Linear dependence of `theta` gives some distribution over azimuthal (meridional) angle. `Sqrt(Pi*L)` multiplier has been chosen due to overall spiral length (to fit L items).

Look at the pole of sphere where periodic table begins - hydrogen at the pole, helium is close to it, lithium is next and so on - forming spiral.

Note that `phi/theta` names differ from common (and wiki page) designations - here theta is azimuthal angle.

Comment: Thanks and am I right that all values of phi in the loop will be always in the range from "Pi to 0" and if I set **i=L** and **i=0** I'll get exactly these two borders "0 and Pi" ? 

Actually I only now noticed the spiral! But why Sqrt, why L and not a size of each object? Is Sqrt(Pi*L) like a formula of a spiral's length? maybe is there some links to math explanation it will be also helpful

Comment: Yes, 0..Pi is range of arccosine principal value. With i=L and 0 you'll get 0 and Pi. Objects should be distributed along all spiral, so it's length has been used. I don't know formula for this spherical spiral length, but it could be deduced through integration over curve element (differential geometry).